# Driving car electrical vacuum pump

Tags: ac, dc, driver, automotive, vacuum

I am trying to drive an electrical vacuum pump from a car directly from 12 VDC.

Earlier, I succeeded with a different pump just by connecting them to DC power, the other pump (different brand) used around 10 A at 13.8 V.

But now I got a new pump (different manufacturer) which does not rotate when I plug the power. It just moves small steps each time I connect it.

It might be an AC pump, which seems strange to me for using it in a car.
Can someone help me understand how to drive it?

I attach the image of the circuit inside after opening the cap in the electric side, next to the two leads.

The model of the pump is 59220-J5000. It looks [exactly like this.](https://www.avito.ru/moskva/zapchasti_i_aksessuary/vakuumnyy_nasos_kia_stinger_1875573480). The resistance between the leads is about 0.2 ohm.

[image: the circuit of the pump]

Comment: Very nicely built inside, apart from that the photo is useless. Link a product description. It seems DC to me.

Comment: Could you attach a picture of the nameplate?

Comment: Is this new vacuum pump from a different car or somewhere else? Red and black are usually DC wires but some small motors run on 90v or even 180v DC.

Comment: How about you link the product? Also consider car picking yards, you can get older models of such things for like $10.

Comment: Nicely made. Nice photo! Much better than most. Could be a brush motor - a segment may be dead. Power and spin shaft by hand while powered if possible. Could be brushless motor and so then would need matching controller. Brushed looks more likely. What is under blue cap at current top of photo?

Comment: probably you need a stronger power supply, that's usually the problem when I connect a motor and it just twitches. connect a small lamp  (orr led ans resistorm, or voltmeter) to the power supply and connect the motor in parallel.

Comment: I added more information: the model of the pump is 59220-J5000. @Jasen, the power supply can provide up to 30 A, which is almost three times more than other pump's consumption.

Comment: stall curren is typically 10 times run current, so 30A may not be enough.  possibly test by connecting it to a car battery.  what is the DC resistance of the motor?

Comment: @Jasen, the resistance through the leads was very low, around 0.2 ohm.

Comment: So 60 A stall current at 12V you need a power supply that can briefly provide that sort of current, maybe adding some ultracapacitors in parallel with your supply could help.

Comment: Maker & model are on pump. Manufacturer may be helpful.

Comment: It's a brake servo pump from a Kia "Stinger"

Comment: @Jasen was right: the motor was stalling since the power supply could not provide enough current. I tried a 100 A power supply and it started properly. It draws around 30 A in steady state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jasen provided the correct answer in the comments: the original power supply could not provide the initial current to start the motor.
After switching to a more powerful (108 A, 30 V) power supply, the pump started properly.